# How to compare two increasing trends to determine if rate of increase is statistically different?

Tags: linear-model

My problem is that I have two groups and I am tracking their procedure cost over 6 years. I know that treatment CAS is significantly more than CEA, however I am trying to find out if the rate of increase of CAS cost is higher than the rate of increase of CEA cost. From doing linear regression, I know that there is an increasing trend for both groups over this time period:

[image]

Copy and paste to recreate the data, which I named "costs":

```
costs = structure(list(Treatment = structure(c("CAS", "CAS", "CAS", "CAS", 
"CAS", "CAS", "CEA", "CEA", "CEA", "CEA", "CEA", "CEA"), label = "", class = 
c("labelled", 
"character")), YEAR = structure(c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015), label = NA_character_, class = 
c("labelled", 
"numeric")), mean = c(17745.4487074494, 18016.9540888478, 18982.2898909046, 
19018.7512920432, 20443.5254030762, 21409.4316258373, 12730.430529664, 
13699.557056951, 14934.790231357, 15194.2972667141, 15039.0566537585, 
15156.1898762083), std.error = c(277.92943520832, 258.299762929203, 
284.525332895525, 294.973620080541, 331.405924818534, 408.182632902199, 
204.395060851366, 241.632349954947, 280.317503863797, 253.915751049086, 
246.127459344887, 265.801844747852)), .Names = c("Treatment", 
"YEAR", "mean", "std.error"), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'd like to be able to say "The rate of cost increase of CAS (is/is not) statistically different than the rate of cost increase of CEA".

The slope for CEA indicates average increase of 469 USD per year, and for CAS it is 732 USD per year and I suspect that this is significantly different.

Specifically, I am wondering if including an interaction term is adequate, for example:

```
lm(mean ~ YEAR + Treatment + Treatment*YEAR, data=costs)
```

Would the p value from the interaction term be considered a moderating variable and answer the statement that I have above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the interaction term is testing for equal slopes.  A small p-value is evidence of different slopes.