# Test for independence of trends

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, independence, trend

Suppose I have two distinct outcomes being tracked over time, A and B. An individual observation can have outcome A, outcome B, both (call it AB), or neither.

If the rate of outcomes A and B are both increasing over time, and the rate of outcome AB is increasing over time as well, it is plausible that the increasing rate of AB is simply the result of the independent increases in rate of A and of B (a reasonable null hypothesis), right? Or it might be increasing faster or slower than would be expected if A and B were independently driving the increase.

How could I statistically test for these different plausible explanations? I know I could compare AB against A or AB against B to see if the trends are different using an interaction effect (per [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/393548/how-to-compare-two-increasing-trends-to-determine-if-rate-of-increase-is-statist)), but don't know how to do both at once, if that makes sense.

EDIT:
This figure shows two of the outcomes (A and AB) over time for different observational units (national, regional, state). Comparing region by region, for instance, it looks like for many regions the trend was similar in the first third or so of the time period, but then outcome AB starts increasing faster than outcome A. I *think* showing that the AB increasing trend is faster than the A trend is easy enough using an interaction effect (see link above).

[image]

I don't have a plot of outcome B handy, but it too shows an increasing trend over time. I could likewise show that AB is increasing faster than B.

But if A and B are both increasing, AB could increase faster than either A or B simply if A and B were independent. (A spatial version would be a plane bisecting a 3D space at an incline on both X and Y dimensions - the slope along the diagonal would be steeper than the slope along either X or Y.) So the questions is how to show if AB is increasing *even faster* than that, or slower (albeit still faster than either A or B).

Comment: Could you give some more details? Show us some plots? I would start looking into Poisson (or logistic) regression

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen added a plot and further explanation, hopefully it makes sense!